# integer64 and Rcpp compatibility

Tags: r, data.table, rcpp, bit64

I will need 64 bits integer in my package in a close future. I'm studying the feasibility based on the [`bit64`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit64/index.html) package. Basically I plan to have one or more columns in a `data.table` with an `interger64` S3 class and I plan to pass this table to C++ functions using Rcpp.

The following [nanotime example](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/creating-integer64-and-nanotime-vectors/) from Rcpp gallery explains clearly how a vector of 64 bits int is built upon a vector of double and explain how to create an `integer64` object from C++ to R.

I'm now wondering how to deal with an `interger64` from R to C++. I guess I can invert the principle.

```
void useInt64(NumericVector v) 
{
    double len = v.size();
    std::vector<int64_t> n(len);

    // transfers values 'keeping bits' but changing type
    // using reinterpret_cast would get us a warning
    std::memcpy(&(n[0]), &(v[0]), len * sizeof(double));

    // use n in further computations
}
```

Is that correct? Is there another way to do that? Can we use a wrapper `as<std::vector<int64_t>>(v)`? For this last question I guess the conversion is not based on a bit to bit copy.

Comment: Looks correct. We are doing just that in a few places for `nanotime` and `RcppCCTZ`, and `bit64` does it.  You have to be careful with rounding though.  In `RcppCCTZ` I added one converter from two doubles.  As for the `as<>` converter: you would have to write one.

Comment: Thanks. I guess you are talking about integer overflow right? No problem I figured out myself that we must be careful. After all `integer64` is a kind of hack.

Comment: `bit64` is pretty careful to take these 64 bits and interpret as an integer. So you can "transport" them via a `numeric` -- with care.  But ... there is nothing Rcpp-specific here, and there is not Rcpp "support" as there is not _native_ integer64 in R we could lean on.

Comment: @Dirk-Eddelbuettel your comment could be an answer here

Comment: @jangorecki Image a :man_shrugging_emoji: here...